# Footnote style using asterisk should have space or no space between symbol and note?

Tags: typography, alignment, typesetting, formatting, publishing

When referencing a footnote using an asterisk or other acceptable symbols such as dagger and double dagger, in the footnote itself do you put a space between the symbol and the note?

Example:

```
This is a reference* to a footnote.
```

Which is the correct footnote format or style?

With space:

```
* Lorem ipsum.
```

Without space:

```
*Lorem ipsum.
```

This confusion is due to the fact that footnote references that uses numbers are shown differently. A fullstop and space is the correct styling. Example.

```
This is a reference¹ to a footnote.

1. Lorem ipsum.
```

Comment: You can't expect to do proper typesetting purely with characters you type in at the keyboard, which is what's needed here. What's a "space"? An en space? An em space? A three/four/five/six-per-em space? A figure space? A punctuation space? A thin space or a hair space? Are you setting these using the fonts superiors? You need a real desktop publishing system for this, or else it just doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually, I think is a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I generally use a narrow space like third, quarter or thin space.

However, if you have multiple footnotes, or they span across multiple lines, or the numbering/symbols take up more space, you then need to use indentation (indents & first line indents).

Taking this one step further you can right align the symbols and left align the text content, thus making the symbols/numbering float to the outside of the text area.

[image]